# Postgres DB user permission

Tags: postgresql

I'm logged in as a user in postgres with PgAdmin tool in Linux connecting remotely but I don't think the user has enough rights. I'm a MySQL experienced user but not so much in Postgres. When I select a table when logged in as the user I get

An error has occurred:

> ERROR:  permission denied for relation acs_activities

how do I add my user "gainpm" to have access to all tables in "projop" database?

Answer (score 1):

You should log in as the table owner (the user you used to create the tables) and then grant the necessary privileges to your user:

```
grant select on acs_activities to your_user;
```

If you want to do that for all tables, you can use:

```
grant select on all tables in schema public to you_user;
```

Or maybe you created them as the superuser, but your regular user should be the real owner, then you should do:

```
alter table acs_activities owner to your_user;
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. First I had to login as superuser

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

then issue

```
ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;
```

Comment: Using a superuser for your regular work is a really bad idea. Do you also work as root all the time in Linux?